# Stub a Promise in PhantomJS/Sinon

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, sinon-chai

I have a class in jquery that calls a service and returns a promise, which is then executed in my main area via a `.done` and Im trying to wrap that call in a another class I have that will make sure multiple calls are not made for the same ID. However I am finding this very very difficult to test as I can not accurcately get the promise working in phantomJS/Sinon. Heres what the area Im trying to test is

```
LOCKER.execute(diagRunId, function (unlock) {
  SERVICE_ACCESSOR.makeCall params)
   .done(function (data) {
     console.log("Success!");
     unlock();
   })
   .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log("Failed!");
     unlock();
   });
});
```

and In my test file I have my `setup` like so

```
var setup = function() {

    P.mock('service-accessor', function () {
        return {
            makeCall: sinon.stub().returns({})
        };
    });

    P.mock('locker', function () {
        var methods = {
            execute: function (lockId, wrapped) {
                console.log('locked - ' + lockId)
                wrapped()
            },
        unlock: sinon.stub()
        };
        return {
            execute: methods.execute,
            unlock: methods.unlock
        };
    });

    P.start();
}
```

with finally the test just calling the method

```
aui.suite('Locker Test', function () {

        aui.test('should lock and then unlock', testFile, {
            setup: setup,
            browser: function () {
                P.when('utils', 'service-accessor','locker').execute(
                    'test', function (SERVICE_ACCESSOR, LOCKER) {
                       
                        UTILS.makeCall("Identifier")
                        expect(LOCKER.unlock).to.have.been.called.once;
                        done();
                    }
                );
            },
            validate: function () {},
        });
});
```

The locker works and begins execution of the service call, but then the service call fails with

```
     Error: PhantomJS: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'SERVICE_ACCESSOR.callService( params).done')` near
L2492>          }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
```

From my understanding my mock should return a just a empty object when its being called, but then I dont understand a) Why its going to fail and b) Whats undefined? My assumption is that its because Im not returning three objects, but Im trying to get it to succeed first! How can I correctly stub/mock this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't make a promise or use a stub. I used the following function that would call the `done` and `fail` in my call instead.

````
function() {
                return { done: function(callback) {
                    if(window.makeParamountCallSuccess) {
                        callback({"data": "data"});
                        return {
                            fail: function(){}
                        }
                    } else {
                        return {
                            fail: function(failCallback){ failCallback("jqXHR", "textStatus", "errorThrown")}
                        }
                    }
                   }
                }
            }```
````